Why does .Net Framework version differ for the same container depending on the hosts version of Windows?
How is it possible that the .Net Framework version within a Docker container is different, dependent on what host machine it runs on?
On my development Windows 11 machine (which is itself .NET Framework Version: 4.8.1 or later):

.NET Framework Version: 4.8

On my development Windows Server 2019 machine (which is itself .NET Framework Version: 4.8):

.NET Framework Version: 4.7.2

Framework versions obtained with code from Microsoft:
$release = Get-ItemPropertyValue -LiteralPath 'HKLM:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full' -Name Release
switch ($release) {
    { $_ -ge 533320 } { $version = '4.8.1 or later'; break }
    { $_ -ge 528040 } { $version = '4.8'; break }
    { $_ -ge 461808 } { $version = '4.7.2'; break }
    { $_ -ge 461308 } { $version = '4.7.1'; break }
    { $_ -ge 460798 } { $version = '4.7'; break }
    { $_ -ge 394802 } { $version = '4.6.2'; break }
    { $_ -ge 394254 } { $version = '4.6.1'; break }
    { $_ -ge 393295 } { $version = '4.6'; break }
    { $_ -ge 379893 } { $version = '4.5.2'; break }
    { $_ -ge 378675 } { $version = '4.5.1'; break }
    { $_ -ge 378389 } { $version = '4.5'; break }
    default { $version = $null; break }
}

if ($version) {
    Write-Host -Object ".NET Framework Version: $version"
} else {
    Write-Host -Object '.NET Framework Version 4.5 or later is not detected.'
}

Docker image is based off of FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows:ltsc2019.
When building the images, part of my setup script installs VS components and workloads (RunProcessChecked is just a helper function that wraps Start-Process):
RunProcessChecked "choco" @("install", "--no-progress", "-y", "vcredist-all", "windows-sdk-10-version-1809-windbg")

$windows_sdk_version = 20348

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vs_buildtools.exe" -OutFile "$env:TEMP\vs_buildtools.exe"

$vs_args = @(
    "--quiet",
    "--wait",
    "--norestart",
    "--nocache",
    "--installPath", "C:\BuildTools",
    "--channelUri", "https://aka.ms/vs/$visual_studio_build/release/channel",
    "--installChannelUri", "https://aka.ms/vs/$visual_studio_build/release/channel",
    "--channelId", "VisualStudio.$visual_studio_build.Release",
    "--productId", "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.BuildTools",
    "--locale", "en-US",
    "--add", "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VCTools",
    "--add", "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.MSBuildTools",
    "--add", "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.NuGet",
    "--add", "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64",
    "--add", "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.ATL"
    "--add", "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.$windows_sdk_version",
    "--add", "Microsoft.Net.Component.4.5.TargetingPack",
    "--add", "Microsoft.Net.Component.4.6.2.TargetingPack",
    "--add", "Microsoft.Net.ComponentGroup.4.6.2-4.7.1.DeveloperTools",
    "--add", "Microsoft.Net.ComponentGroup.DevelopmentPrerequisites",
    "--add", "Microsoft.NetCore.Component.SDK",
    "--add", "Microsoft.NetCore.Component.Runtime.3.1"
)

RunProcessChecked "$env:TEMP\vs_buildtools.exe" $vs_args

I actually don't know why .Net Framework 4.8 is even showing as the framework version in the container when run on my Windows 11 machine as it's never installed.
This is causing me no end of problems and violates everything I thought I knew about Docker and containers (i.e. you build and image once and it's the same everywhere). How do I ensure the .Net Framework version remains the same?

How did you ensure that you are really using the same container?

It's the same image that I published to an internal registry. I understand the difference between image and container, don't get me wrong. So how does the container get it's .Net Framework?

Can you share more details about this? Are you sure that you're using the exact same image in both cases? Maybe you're using different versions? As you haven't shared any details about your setup, how should we know how the images are built?

Added some more info specific to the installation of VS workloads and components. I pull the same image label from the registry on each machine. I build and push from the Windows 11 machine. If that's giving me different image versions then I don't understand why,

To my knowledge, Windows Server 2019 does not ship with .NET Framework 4.8 - it ships with 4.7.2 OOB - and your $vs_args command does not include the 4.8.x targeting tools, it only goes up to 4.7.1 - so could that be it?

Ah. I see re the comment about Windows Server 2019 only shipping with .Net Framework 4.7.2. That's relevant because the base Docker image is windows:ltsc2019 because it needs to run on a Windows Server 2019 host in process isolation mode. But I don't think that only installing up to 4.7.1 targeting tools is the issue since it's reporting 4.8 when run on my Windows 11 desktop PC.

@junglie85 My understanding is that when you use Docker-for-Windows, the OS base image (the kernel, etc) must match your local computer exactly, otherwise if you're running WS2019 on a Windows 11 desktop then that sounds like a VM (unless Docker-for-Windows also lets you control VMs?)

Thank you both for your pointed questions. This is 100% user error. I had a Docker image based on ‘windows/server:lts2022’ and then built another from ‘windows:lts2019’ for the Windows 11 and Server 2019 hosts respectively. Somehow I managed to have 2 different images with the same tag. Questions about guaranteeing the same container version and about the default .Net Framework finally helped me realise the problem and my confusion about the cause.
